# Collect usage clicks for heat maps on a desktop application

Tags: ribbon, usability, user-experience

We are creating an experimental version of a desktop application with the new office ribbon interface and want to do some usability tests. I am sure there are other engineers here who have faced the problem. Could you share your experience on what tests you did for that transition. My idea is to capture users' interaction with the application via usage clicks and build heat maps. What sort of tools can I use to do that?

Answer (score 0):

**Usability testing analysis software** will help you capture users' clicks on an experimental web app that is not yet ready to be published externally. I have used OvoLogger, by Ovo Studios. Their Event Tracker tool, a component of OvoLogger, captures user clicks, highlights them, and generates post-test reports in a variety of formats. It also highlights the user's cursor and mouse clicks, so observers watching the usability test can clearly see whether the user is just hovering over a link or actually clicking it.

**Live-site analytics tools** like Google Analytics, Clicktale and CrazyEgg all provide heatmaps, but your mileage will vary. CrazyEgg claims to have more accurate heat maps than Google Analytics or ClickTale, because they capture the precise location of the user's click rather than capturing page-level clicks with multiple possible targets. If you are looking at doing multivariate analysis in the future, you will want to know exactly where the user clicked (target A, or target B), so you will be able to discern which experimental option garners more clicks.

Comment: thanks Linda, i am writing my own version of a data collection tool since the tools and analysis is really expensive..

Comment: One of the drawbacks of these tools is that they tell you what, but they don't offer up the why. It might be less expensive and a lot less work to watch users work for a few hours. You'll also be able to ask them what caused them to click on this rather than that, which might tell you more than a heatmap. And you can do it before you're finished, so you can make adjustments along the way. Best to you!